# NSEncoding for composed custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom class

```
@interface MyDevice : NSObject,<NSCoding>{
NSString *devicename;
.
.
MyBattery *batteryInfo;
}
```

where MyBattery is another custom class. I want to use encoding on MyDevice as below:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject: devicename];
    .
    .
    [encoder encodeObject: batteryInfo]; // Is this Possible??
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder: decoder];

    if (nil != self) {
        devicename = [decoder decodeObject];
        .
        .

        batteryInfo = [decoder decodeObject]; // Is this possible??
    }

    return self;
}
```

But this is crashing saying `NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:` does not call encodeWithCoder. I tried having NScoding for MyBattery. But same result. Can anyone put some light on it?

Comment: Your `MyBattery` class also needs to conform to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work your custom class MyBattery should itself be NSCoding compliant.

If yes, Try to use below for batteryInfo

```
NSData * encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:batteryInfo];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:encodedData  forKey:@"batteryInfo"];
```

Also use NSKeyedUnarchiver to decode.

```
NSData *data= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"batteryInfo"];
MyBattery *batteryInfo= [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

You Will be required to save the data in NSDefaults or some file.

Please verify the result and let know.

Comment: Yes. MyBattery is also NSCoding compliant.

Comment: I need one encoded object of MyDevice( that encodes composed object too) to send object through NSNotiifcation. my requirement is not to use persistent data like NSuserdefaults. Do you mean, above code to be added inside encodeWithCoder of MyDevice?

Comment: Yes this should be part of MyDevice class for archiving MyBattery. Since you need to transfer the object just skip saving in NSdefaults.

Comment: Thanks bllakjakkless. It is resolved. I added the encode and decode for batteryInfo as you suggested. Thank you!